# Calling a stored procedures within the same schema from a SP

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, sql-pl

How can I call a stored procedure in the same schema without specifying the full schema name when coding another stored procedure. These are SQL PL procedures within DB2.

First SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.SP_TEST
  LANGUAGE SQL
  BEGIN
  END
```

Creating a SP calling this SP directly without a schema name causes a compilation error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.SP_TEST2
  LANGUAGE SQL
  BEGIN
    CALL SP_TEST();
  END
```

It will throw:

> No authorized routine named "SP_TEST" of type "PROCEDURE" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=3.53.71

Directly giving the full schema name works:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.SP_TEST2
  LANGUAGE SQL
  BEGIN
    CALL MYSCHEMA.SP_TEST();
  END
```

However if I ever move to a different schema I will have to replace that references all over the place. Is there a suitable workaround or nicer solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CURRENT PATH` special register is used to resolve calls to unqualified stored procedures and functions.  `CURRENT SCHEMA` is used to resolve unqualified object names.

By default, `CURRENT PATH` has IBM functions plus your AUTHID:

```
$ db2 "values substr(current path,1,60)"

1
------------------------------------------------------------
"SYSIBM","SYSFUN","SYSPROC","SYSIBMADM","IBJORHOV"

  1 record(s) selected.
```

You can modify this with the `SET CURRENT PATH` statement.

When you create a stored procedure, DB2 takes note of the value of `CURRENT PATH` at compilation time and uses them to resolve unqualified stored procedure and function calls within the stored procedure.  The same logic applies for `CURRENT SCHEMA` and unqualified table names.

So the proper way to allow unqualified procedure and function calls within a stored procedure is to set the `CURRENT PATH` register and then creating the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Ommitting SCHEMA name is discouraged. Keep your schema names in your calls. If you move to a different schema, you have to do this by extracting/altering the SQL script anyway.

Comment: Do you have any IBM technote or something verifying that claim? From previous Oracle programming I'm not remembering that it was a big deal there.

Answer (score 1):

The `SET SCHEMA` command allows you to change the current schema:

```
SET CURRENT SCHEMA FOO;
CALL MY_PROC_THAT_RESIDES_IN_FOO();
```

It is not so easy to use set the schema to a dynamic value, though.  You would have to either:

1. Do something with host variables (if you are within a calling application) or
2. Build and execute a dynamic SQL statement string.

At that point it is probably becoming more trouble than it's worth.

More information can be found at the [documentation for the `SET SCHEMA` command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_setschema.htm).

Comment: It seems like the compiler ignores the current schema, when creating a stored procedure. Setting the current schema within the procedure seems to be ignored as well. Setting the current schema before creating the two procedures above still throws the same error.

Comment: I did test that a procedure gets created in the current schema that has been set, but, sure enough, this is ignored for the `CALL` statement.  Strange.